# Data not populating in mobile browser when using Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am running into an issue with mobile browsers. My web app is built using .Net 6.0 and the MVC architecture. It runs perfectly fine on desktop browsers, however when trying to run it on Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge mobile browsers, no data is populating on log in. I have been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out what could be causing this issue.

Has anyone encountered this? I am feeling like it is something simple that I am just missing.

Comment: Where does the data come from upon login? Place a breakpoint at the request and response and let us know if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It was something incredibly simple like I thought. Essentially I had an IndexModel that wasn't playing nicely with Chrome. Additionally, IIS was caching my code the bug fix was not being applied, resulting in me beating my head against a wall for hours.